# Character Encoding Issue in Python/MySQL Based Pipeline

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, unicode, character-encoding

I am having trouble getting the encoding/decoding working properly with an application that I am developing with the following components:

1. Python 3.6
2. BeautifulSoup
3. **Scraped** web page using UTF-8
4. MySQL
5. json
6. Lambda

When I get the data into the front-end (Alexa), it includes the unicode characters (e.g., \u00e2\u0080\u0099) in some cases.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

**Here are code snippets from the entire pipeline:**

The original web page is:
Checked document.characterSet in Chrome Developer Tools
[image: Webpage Character Encoding]

I am **scraping** with this Python/BeautifulSoup code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pymysql
    if page_response.status_code == 200:
        page_content = BeautifulSoup(page_response.content, "html.parser")    
        if str(page_content.find(attrs={'id': 'main'})).find(page_test) != -1:
            for table_row in page_content.select("div#page_filling_chart center table tr"):
                cells = table_row.findAll('td')
                if cells:
                    records += 1
                    bo_entry.title = cells[2].text.strip()
```

Putting data into the database with this:

```
connection = pymysql.connect(
        host=rds_host,
        user=name,
        password=password,
        db=db_name
        )
    try:
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            # UPSERT: https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-insert-if-row-does-not-exist-upsert-in-mysql/
            sql = (
                    f"REPLACE INTO weekend_box_office(weekend_date, market, title_id, title,gross,total_gross,rank_order, previous_rank, distributor, distributor_id, change_pct, theaters, per_theater, week_in_release, gross_num, total_gross_num)"
                    f"VALUE(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s);"
                )
            data = (
                    bo_entry.weekend, bo_entry.market, bo_entry.title_id, bo_entry.title, bo_entry.gross, bo_entry.total_gross, 
                    bo_entry.rank, bo_entry.previous_rank, bo_entry.distributor, bo_entry.distributor_id, bo_entry.change_pct, bo_entry.theaters,
                    bo_entry.per_theater, bo_entry.weeks_in_release, bo_entry.gross_num, bo_entry.total_gross_num
                    )
#            print(sql)
```

The current database collation and character set are set to:
[image: Database Character Set]

The MySQL Table Collation that the data is stored in is this:
[image: Table Character Encoding]

I fetch data from the database using this Python 3.6 code:

```
connection = pymysql.connect(
        host=rds_host,
        user=name,
        password=password,
        db=db_name
        )

        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            sql = (
                    f"select weekend_date, title_id, title, gross, gross_num, total_gross, total_gross_num, CONCAT(cast(ROUND(gross_num / total_gross_num * 100,1) as CHAR),'%') as weekend_pct, week_in_release "
                    "from weekend_box_office "
                    f"where weekend_date = '{weekend_text}' "
                    f"order by gross_num desc limit {limit_row_no}; "
                )
            try:
                cursor.execute(sql)
                result = cursor.fetchall()              
                for row in result:
                    title = row[2]
```

This is what it looks like when I place a breakpoint and exam it in the Variable Explorer of Spyder.
[image: Variable Explorer]

When I return it, it looks like this:
[image: Returned as Str]

using this code:
response_text += (
f"led by {title} pulling in ${SpeechUtils.spoken_human_format(gross_num)}. "
)
return response_text

When I return it from Lambda using the json Python library, it looks like this:
[image: Output from JSON Module]
return {
'statusCode': 200,
'body': json.dumps(speak_top5(BoxOffice.get_previous_friday())),
'headers': {
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
},

Comment: NOTE: I was doing some more research and did read this article and found that adding the parameter "ensure_ascii=False" to json.dumps(x, ensure_ascii=False) help.  There is still an issue with the accent characters, but it removes the Unicode symbols.

Answer (score 0):

Try after changing the mysql connection charset to `charset='utf8'`.

```
connection = pymysql.connect(
    host=rds_host,
    user=name,
    password=password,
    db=db_name,
    charset='utf8'
    )
```

See the detailed information from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through?noredirect=1&lq=1)